# Rollup, vue, syntax error in style section

Tags: vuejs3, rollupjs

I'm using a very simple style setup in my vue component

```
<style scope="local">
.n-transfer {
  height: 500px;
}
</style>
```

and rollup setup is simple as well

```
// ...
import vue from 'rollup-plugin-vue'
// ...
import babel from '@rollup/plugin-babel'
import css from "rollup-plugin-import-css";
// ...
export default pages.map( p =>
    { return {
//...
        plugins: [
            vue(/* options */),
            replace({
                'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify( 'development' ),
                preventAssignment: true
            }),
            alias({
                //customResolve: nodeResolve({ extensions: ['.js','.vue'] }),
                customResolve: function(source,importer,options) {
                    console.log( { source, importer, option } );
                    return null;
                },
                entries: [
                    { find: '@',
                      replacement: path.resolve(root,'src')
                    }
                ]
            }),
            commonjs(),
            babel(babelOptions),
            css(),
            nodeResolve({
                // pass custom options to the resolve plugin
                extensions: ['.js','.vue'],
                moduleDirectories: ['node_modules']
            }),
        ]
})
```

With this setup, I'm getting an error

```
[!] (plugin babel) SyntaxError: /usr/home/tarkhil/average_bot/src/components/Settings.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=47aa12d3&scope=local&lang.css: Unexpected token (2:0)

  1 |
> 2 | .n-transfer {
    | ^
  3 |   height: 500px;
  4 | }
  5 |
src/components/Settings.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=47aa12d3&scope=local&lang.css (2:0)
```

Looks like rollup is trying to process style section as javascript or something. The error should be very silly, but I can't find it.